# Error en el reportviewer asp.net en Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

he tratado de solucionar un error que aparece en el computador de otra persona el siguiente error:

Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalProcessingException' en Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll pero no se controló en el código del usuario

Justo se cae cuando se utiliza parametros(report.SetParameters(parametro)), el asunto es que funciona en mi computador, también funciona en el computador de un amigo, pero copio mi proyecto que funciona en los otros computadores al computador de cierta persona da el error ya descrito.

En mi computador que funciona, tiene win7, framework 4.5.1. Visual Studio Profesional 2013, instalado Microsoft ReportViewer 2015 runtime.

En el computador de mi amigo que funciona, tiene win10, framework 4.4.1 y Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 ReportViewer 2015 runtime., y el Visual Studio 2015.

En el computador de la persona que no funciona el reportviewer, tiene win10,framework 4.5.1 Visual Studio Ultimate 2013, instalado Microsoft ReportViewer 2015 runtime.

Me he cabeceado pensando cual será el problema, pero en ninguna parte he 
encontrado la solución, espero que poder encontrar la solución.

Comment: checa si tiene los ensamblados sino instalale el runtime, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45496

Comment: que debería tener en los ensamblados y donde?

Comment: @Danilo por favor edita tu pregunta agregando la información de las características de los equipos en los que has hecho pruebas: `sistema operativo, frameworks instalados (y sus versiones), etc`.

Comment: Los ensamblados estan en c:\Program Files)\Microsoft Visual Studio(tu _version)\ReportViewer y contienen "COSAS" para hacer funcionar tus reportes, en tu maquina no hay problema porque lo integra con el visual studio pero en la maquina del cliente no es posible instalar visual y para eso debes usar su runtime

Comment: Otra cosar estas fijando en un path tus .rdl o .rdlc que seran usados.

Comment: Ok @MauricioAriasOlave, agregue mas descripción de los equipos en la pregunta

Comment: @Danilo, la única diferencia que veo es el `framework 4.4.1`. Abre el proyecto en el equipo que no funciona tu proyecto y busca en las `Referencias` del proyecto esta dll: `Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalProcessingException' en Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll`, sino existe, cópiala de otra máquna que la tenga y agrégala a ese equipo _(pégala en la carpeta Bin del proyecto)_. Prueba de nuevo y actualiza tu pregunta si hubo algún cambio.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ya solucione el problema, habia que hacer una referencia desde el visual studio a una dll del disco C:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Acepta la respuesta mediante un click en el check verde del costado :D Así ayudas a mantener la salud del sitio por % de respuestas resueltas